# Displaying Image in ListBox based on FileName

Tags: c#, wpf, image, listbox

I am trying to display an `Image` in a `ListBox` for each Filetype returned from the database. Below is the code I am using. I think my problem is I am  trying to pass a property from the db to DirectoryInfo Property. Everything is correct until I get to `FileImage = di.GetFiles();`  Then I get a exception cannot find file in bin folder.  What is the best way of accomplishing this?   Thanks for any replies.

Converter stored in a folder with other converters(not in code behind).

```
public class ConvertFileImage : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value as string == string.Empty) return null;

            var file = @"Media/file_" + value.ToString().Substring(1) + ".png";
            ImageSource src = new BitmapImage(new Uri(file, UriKind.Relative));
            return src;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Class that stores the files from the db

```
public class FilesFromDb
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public byte[] Data { get; set; }
     public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

Property the listbox is binding to

```
public ObservableCollection<FilesFromDb> Files
{
     get
     {
          return mFiles;
     }
}
```

Property to get the image from the filename

```
public FileInfo[] FileImage { get; set; }
```

I am trying to use a foreach loop to take the Filename from the database and use that for the directory, I am failing here.

```
foreach (var imagetype in Files)
                    {
                        var di = new DirectoryInfo(imagetype.FileName);
                        FileImage = di.GetFiles();


                    }
```

Then I was binding to the converter in the xaml

```
<converters:ConvertFileImage x:Key="ConvertFileImage"/>
```

This is within a listbox item template with the listbox ItemsSource="{Binding Files}"

```
 <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0">
      <Image Source="{Binding Extension, Converter={StaticResource ConvertFileImage}}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
  </Grid>
```

If the file was stored locally I could use something like this

```
 var di = new DirectoryInfo("c:/FilesFolder");  // I think that would work, but not using a property from db
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After re-reading your question a couple of times I think I understand where you were trying to go. I believe your `ConvertFileImage` should look a little more like this:

```
public class ConvertFileImage : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
     {
         if (value as string == string.Empty) return null;

         var file = @"Media/file_" + Path.GetExtension(value.ToString()) + ".png";
         ImageSource src = new BitmapImage(new Uri(file, UriKind.Relative));
         return src;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then your binding should just pass in the filename:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0">
    <Image Source="{Binding FileName, Converter={StaticResource ConvertFileImage}}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: All that it is storing is Name.doc or Name.pdf etc

Comment: Thanks, I see but I cant use RootFilePath as these Files are coming from the db then stored in the Files ObservableCollection.  (imagetype.FileName) is a property storing the filename eg.(Test.docx)  from the database.

Comment: What are you doing with `FileImage` ?

Comment: That is what I was trying the first time, but it does not work, was just showing what I had tried.

Comment: Ok, I think I went the wrong direction then. I have modified the code from above. Looking at your `ConvertFileImage` above, you are trying to pass it a filename, parse for the extention then map that to a image which is embedded in your WCF project?